# Excel VBA: Can't capture key stroke

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that gives the user 6 choices. They can either click on the appropriate choice on the userform or press a number 1 thru 6 on the keyboard. My issue is that the keypress or keydown event never triggers. I need to capture the key pressed and check if it in number 1 thru 6 "when the userform is displayed" to run the next sub. This is my latest attempt. No matter what event I try to capture nothing seems to capture a key being pressed. When I put a break point on the beginning of the sub it never get called.

```
Private Sub Userform_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 49 Then
        MsgBox "You pressed the '1' key!"
    ElseIf KeyCode = 50 Then
        MsgBox "You pressed the '2' key!"
    ElseIf KeyCode = 51 Then
        MsgBox "You pressed the '3' key!"
    ElseIf KeyCode = 52 Then
        MsgBox "You pressed the '4' key!"
    ElseIf KeyCode = 53 Then
        MsgBox "You pressed the '5' key!"
    ElseIf KeyCode = 54 Then
        MsgBox "You pressed the '6' key!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the focus when you press the key?

Comment: The form actually has no focus point there are 6 frames with image controls in them. there are no labels or textboxes no other controls. I have everything set to none clickable to resolve this issue. If I had to guess I would say it is frame1 with focus just because it probably is set to focus when the userform initializes. But no sub, command or user can set the focus right now.

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you GSerg, this got me thinking. After testing all controls for focus it turned up that when the form is initializing the focus is being set to the image control in the third frame. Printing the list of controls to the immediate window, looking at the creation sequence, tab index, and tab stop nothing shows why VBA chose this control to put focus on. I setfocus in the initialize sub now and have adjusted the keydown to it and everything is working. Again Thank you GSerg.